# Sentences using the X bar theory

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, x-bar-theory

I am studying linguistics and currently have Syntax and am trying to understand the X bar theory. Could someone please draw a tree of the sentence down below for me so I could get a better understanding of how the theory works. My professor does not give complex examples in class. All help is much appreciated.

**Sentence:** By signing the contract, you allowed your broker to access your personal information.

Comment: You should look at the help center about off topic questions, esp. asking people to draw trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to give it go with drawing it. This also depends on what your professor says is where the subject goes. So, for me, the subject of the sentence/phrase was in the Spec of VP. and then it would raise up through the CPs until it got to the top. Your prof may do it different. Be careful to look for adjuncts, things that don't need to be there for it to make sense, and that will help. Understand that an XP can have multiple bars down... Things that take more than one or two theta roles such as "mary told jack" told has the theta roles of Mary telling and jack being told. Think of how these can be broken down. Look for DPs and start there.

Also look in your book for examples or email your prof for help.